# iPhone 2D Game programming

Tags: iphone

I would like to start a project about creating a 2D game for iPhone. I have already created some iPhone apps but none concerning game. The idea is simple : the user must drive a ball into a simple route composed of some obstacles before he gets cached by a wall that always go done. (I don't know if it make sense to you but the game environment will be simple).

I posted here because I have some questions :

- What should I use ? Opengl ES or only UIView objects ?
- Is there some framework that could help me ?

All ideas, advices, suggestions, links for good tutorials are welcome !

Thanks in advance for your help.

Ps: forgive my english, it's not my first language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are focusing on 2D only, something like [Cocos 2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) would save you a lot of steps and let to focus on your game development.

It handles scene management, particle effects, sprite animation, physics, etc.

Answer (score 2):

My personal favorite for 2D development is [Corona](http://anscamobile.com/corona/).