# IPhone game development - what should I use for developing 2D games?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The title is very descriptive, I want to start developing games for the iphone and don't know where to start.

I would like to know what tools are available for this.

Should I start with a prebuilt game sdk?

Should I develop in C, C++ or Objective-C ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone 2D Game programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167710/iphone-2d-game-programming)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org) is popular, and pretty simple/well thought out.

Comment: Ray Wanderlich has some cocos2d-for-iPhone tutorials: http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

There are a handful of tools out there that simplify game development on the iPhone. Three that come to mind: [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/), [Box2D](http://www.box2d.org/) and [Chipmunk](http://code.google.com/p/chipmunk-physics).

Comment: to be specific Cocos2d deals with Scenes, Layers, and sprites, and organization and animation thereof. Box2D and Chipmunk are physics engines, these things can be used together or independently. Although I can't imagine using Box2D and Chipmunk in the same project.

Answer (score 0):

[Corona SDK](http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/) is also a fantastic way to go if you want a cross platform game.  You do all of your dev in Lua and can deploy to iOS as well as Android devices.

It also comes with Box2D physics built in.

Comment: thanks brandontreb, cross platform, interesting.
but just for now 1 step at a time.
I'm a newbie. :)

Comment: Totally, that's why I suggested Corona.  It's **super** easy to get up and running.  But I agree with the guys above as well, cocos2D is fantastic as well!